# What's the point in checking the training's data accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning

I am seeing a tutorial in Machine Learning and it checks the accuracy of both the training and testing datasets.

For example:

```
ridge01 = Ridge(alpha=0.1).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Which gives:

```
Training set score: 0.93
Test set score: 0.77
```

I am wondering since the training dataset was visible shouldn't it have 100% accuracy? Therefore why is it a different value and why is it important?

Comment: Why should the training data have 100% accuracy?

Comment: because it is included in the training process and it is visible, I suppose. Please explain

Comment: But the model does not hit every value exactly, much like how a best-fit line follows the trend of the data rather than hitting every point exactly. (More formally, the model predicts an expected value, say probability of 0.9 to flip heads. However, nature does the coin flip, and even if $p=0.9$ for heads, the coin comes up tails 10% of the time, hence lower than 100% accuracy.)

Comment: In practice you mean we don't use the whole dataset for training, therefore some part of it will be unknown eventually?

Comment: We use some subset of the available to assess model performance (cross-validation, etc). That is separate from what I mean. You seem to want to look at the answer and then report that value as the prediction, such as predicting yesterday's weather or stock prices. That is problematic.

Comment: So why do we check the accuracy of the training dataset? and what does it mean for the model in general and for the test's dataset accuracy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101513/discussion-between-dave-and-user12436030).

Answer (score 0):

Performance on unseen data is more important. However, a wide gap between in-sample and out-of-sample performance would be indicative of overfitting, while poor performance in both would indicate that you have not yet captured the trend.

For instance, say that you want accuracy above 90% but get 30% (both out of sample). How do you proceed? If your in-sample performance is 100%, you would focus on variance reduction methods, such as neuron dropout in a neural net, using fewer parameters in a logistic regression, or elastic net regularization. If your in-sample performance is only 31%, then you know that you haven't modeled much of anything yet, and you have to focus on bias reduction.

You can always have a high-bias/low-variance model by randomly guessing based on the ratio of categories. (Example: If you have 10,000 photos of dogs and 10,000 photos of cats, randomly guess "dog" and "cat" 50% of the time each. You will have 50% accuracy in-sample and 50% accuracy out-of-sample.) The trick to machine learning is chipping away at the bias without sending the variance sky-high.